# How to put these 2 similar methods into one module in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models using 2 similar methods. Both of them called are `generate` and both are called by `before_save`. I want to refactor them into one. How can I do that?

```
#model1's generate
before_save :generate
def generate
  self.slug = self.title.gsub(' ', '-').downcase
end

#model2‘s generate
before_save :generate
def generate
  self.slug = self.name.gsub(' ', '-').downcase
end
```

Comment: Use this approach: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3372-put-chubby-models-on-a-diet-with-concerns):

```
module Slugged
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save :generate
  end

  def slugged_attr
    name
  end

  def generate
    self.slug = self.slugged_attr.gsub(' ', '-').downcase
  end
end
```

And then include it into your models.

```
include Slugged
```

Add following method to your first model. It will overwrite slugged_attr in concern:

```
def slugged_attr
  title
end
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, but in model1's generate, it should be `self.title` not `self.name`, how to solve this?

Comment: Try to use alias_attribute or name method for model1.

Comment: I updated my answer for general case. Just overwrite slugged_attr method.